# How to create checkbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox, uikit

I have taken two custom buttons and one method, to set their check and uncheck

In viewdidload() i have written like this..

```
[checkbox_01 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkbox_02 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
isChecked_01 = NO; //declared as boolean to change check and uncheck for button one
isChecked_02 = NO; //declared as boolean to change check and uncheck for button two
```

And in method

```
-(IBAction)checkboxOnClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        if (isChecked_01 == NO) {
            [checkbox_01 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isChecked_01 = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [checkbox_01 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isChecked_01 = NO;
        }
    }

    if (sender.tag == 2) {
        if (isChecked_02 == NO) {
            [checkbox_02 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isChecked_02 = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [checkbox_02 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isChecked_02 = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

is there any other way to create check boxes in ios..? i have taken each checkbox with one isChecked boolean value for it.. is there posibilities to use only one boolean for entire check list.....

Comment: What's your question? Are you having a problem with the posted code? If so, what is the problem? Be specific.

Comment: A custom control would be much better than doing what you are doing.

Comment: i have just updated the question.. please help me in coding i'm new to ios

Comment: Please stop adding needless tags and please format your code properly.

Comment: check this out, take inspiration https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bfpapercheckbox

Comment: i opened the suggested link.. but i'm not getting the answer for my question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [selected](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/selected) property (inherited from UIControl) instead of your isChecked_01 and isChecked_02:

```
[checkbox_01 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkbox_02 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[checkbox_01 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkbox_02 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

- (IBAction)checkboxOnClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code, might be useful to if you want to do customization with checkboxes

https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

**In Storyboard**

1. Set default checkbox image as like below.

[image]

2. Change the **State Config** to **Selected** and add image like checkbox enabled

[image]

**In CODE**
**Objective C**

```
- (IBAction)btnCheckTerms:(UIButton *)sender {

_btnCheckboxTerms.selected = !_btnCheckboxTerms.selected; }
```

**SWIFT**

```
    @IBAction func btnCheckTerms(sender : UIButton) {

_btnCheckboxTerms.isSelected = !_btnCheckboxTerms.isSelected; }
```

**Extra Tips**

Use material Icons rather than normal icon images.